# Trace, eigenvalues and functional calculus

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a (possibly unbounded) self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space. Assume that we for some reason know that the point spectrum of $T$ consists of a finite number of eigenvalues $\lambda _1, \lambda _2, \ldots ,\lambda _N$ and that $T$ in addition to this has some continuous spectrum. Let $f(T)$ be defined for instance as in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus

(or in some other familiar way, e.g. the Cauchy-Green formula or using the Fourier transform) for appropriate functions $f$.

If $\Pi _p$ denotes the projection onto the point spectrum is it then true that $\Pi _p f(T)$ is a trace class operator? In that case, does it hold that 
$$
\operatorname{Tr} (\Pi _p f(T))= \sum _{j=1}^N f(\lambda _j) \quad ?
$$

Comment: No, for instance take $T$ to be the identity operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and $f(x) = x$. You'd have to at least assume that the eigenspaces corresponding to $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_N$ are finite-dimensional.

Comment: With eigenvalues, you mean finite dimensional eigenspaces? Then the answer is yes.

Comment: @András: no, it's still false because $f$ could collapse some continuous spectrum into point spectrum. E.g., $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: @NikWeaver: I confess I do not understand. Then $\Pi_p f(T)$ is an operator acting on a finite dimensional space (if I understand the definitions correctly).

Comment: If $f(x) = 1$ then $\prod_p f(T) = f(T) = I$ is not trace class for any $T$.

Comment: In this case we can assume all eigenspaces to be finite dimensional. The assumption I have on $f$ is that it should belong to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ (Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions).

Comment: @NikWeaver: I assumed $\Pi_p$ is the projection on the point spectrum of $T$, not of $f(T)$.

Comment: @András Bátkai: Yes, $\Pi _p$ is the projection onto the point spectrum of $T$.

Comment: @Alex: so you're asking whether a finite rank operator is trace class? Voting to close!

Comment: Well, what I actually want to know is if the formula for the trace is true (and at first I did not know if the eigenspaces were finite dimensional in my case).

Comment: Well, to summarize the comments of @NikWeaver and myself, if the eigenspaces are finite dimensional, then it is true and your formula follows in a straightforward way from the spectral theory of selfadjoint operators. Otherwise in general it is not true, you need assumptions on your function.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the paper on Berezin inequality:

http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~ysafarov/Publications/ber_gord.pdf